# Base class no longer working after upgrading to Spring Cloud Contract 1.2.0

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am in the process of upgrading to Spring Cloud Edgware.RELEASE, and I've got a question about how to properly set up a base class for Spring Cloud Contract tests. Following is what I have currently as a base class that works through Dalston.SR5:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Bootstrap.class})
@DirtiesContext
public class ConsumerDrivenContractTests {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

  @Test
  public void generateTestsFromGroovyFiles() {

  }

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    DefaultMockMvcBuilder defaultMockMvcBuilder =
        MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain);
    MockMvc mockMvc = defaultMockMvcBuilder.build();
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
  }

}
```

Upon upgrading to Edgware.RELEASE, my `import com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;` no longer resolves, which is confusing. The Spring Cloud Contract documentation states "by default, Rest Assured 3.x is added to the classpath" (see http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#maven-rest-assured), and the example given shows how to use Rest Assured 2.x with the `<groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>` dependency. However, the `<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>` for 1.2.0.RELEASE pulls in the `<groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>` dependencies. Given the documentation, I was expecting the `com.jayway...` jars to be resolved.

Is my base class approach still valid upon upgrading to 1.2.0.RELEASE, and if so, do I need to explicitly add the `com.jayway...` dependencies to my pom.xml file?  If so, it would be helpful if the documentation stated this.

Comment: The documentation explains exactly what you have to do. Basically, you should just copy paste. You have to provide the dependencies to the plugin's classpath. The docs precisely tell you how your pom should look like. What exactly would you like the docs to state?

Comment: Why do I have to add the dependencies if Rest Assured 3.x is added by default? I tried changing the import to `import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;`, but the generated test fails with errors like `package com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.specification does not exist`.

Comment: Let me quote the docs. `By default, Rest Assured 3.x is added to the classpath`. RestAssured 3.x. has imports `io.restassured` and they show up in your generated tests. You, in your base class have `com.jayway` which is RestAssured 2.x. So your generated tests require you to use `io.restassured` imports in your base class. So either you fix your base class to use Rest Assured 3.x or you have to provide an explicit dependency to Rest Assured 2.x. in your plugin to fix the imports in the generated tests. It's all written in the documentation with an example.

Comment: Marcin, I apologize. This is a PIBKAC error on my part. My test class didn't have the `com.jayway` imports specified. Only the generated test class did. It ended up being an issue with my parent POM having Edgware.RELEASE specified, which pulls in SCC 1.2.0.RELEASE, and my project POM specifying an older vesion of the SCC Maven plugin, thus generating a test class with the `com.jayway...` classes imported.

Comment: NP. I've written my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rest Assured 3.x is added to the classpath. RestAssured 3.x. has imports `io.restassured` and they show up in your generated tests. You, in your base class have `com.jayway` which is RestAssured 2.x. So your generated tests require you to use `io.restassured` imports in your base class. So either you fix your base class to use Rest Assured 3.x or you have to provide an explicit dependency to Rest Assured 2.x. in your plugin to fix the imports in the generated tests.